# Retrofit 2 on Android 6 sets zero path parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 library version 2.3.0 and all of a sudden it started replacing integer path parameters with zero instead of the actual number.

I am using Kotlin (1.2.21) and I have a method like:

```
@GET("posts/{postId}")
fun getPosts(@Path("postId") postId: Long): Single<Post>
```

This worked as should but now when I run my app on Android 6 (both a devices and an emulator) the `postId` path parameter is always a zero i.e. `posts/0` is called. Android 7 and 8 are fine. There was no change to the Retrofit and OkHttp versions, also the interface has not changed.

I have looked into the built request and the `OkHttpCall` inside has `args` array with one value of type `Long` with value 0. This is only on Android 6, others have the correct value there. The `ServiceMethod` has the correct URL set in the interface and it has one `ParameterHandler` for the `postId` of type `BuiltInConverter.ToStringConverter`.

App is multiDexed and ProGuard is not used. What could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was caused by the Instant Run. Retrofit works perfectly after I disabled it.